# How do you disable keyboard inputs?

Tags: keyboard

I have this laptop I usually have next to me, I use it for stuff like YouTube, Discord and others, just so I won't lag my main PC. I use a program called "Input Director" to easily control both laptops.
Yesterday I accidentally spilled some water on the laptop keyboard, and now it's randomly pressing buttons.
Is there a way to make it ignore all input from the laptop keyboard but still accept input from Input Director / other **external** keyboards?

The F- keys on the keyboard are broken so I can't just use the "FN- F6" to disable the keyboard, I already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have small enough screwdrivers and you're comfortable opening the bottom (or in some cases the top depending on the model, google/youtube search "keyboard replacement for (make/model)" to see how), of the laptop and disconnecting the keyboard ribbon cable that *should* do the trick... or perhaps disable the device in device manager

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling the keyboard in Device Manager. The laptop keyboard should be listed under Keyboards, right-click and select `Disable`. If the keyboard doesn't disable, try another one, as there will be one keyboard listed for every driver installed (such as keyboard drivers for remote software, if installed).

If you break something, resulting in no keyboard input ability, and need a keyboard, you can plug in a USB keyboard, or use the on screen keyboard (type `osk` in the Start menu search or the Run command).